# Python 3 classes __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, arguments, init

Here is the code:

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}+({}i)".format(self.real, self.imaginary)
    def add(self, second):
        return Complex(self.real + second.real, self.imaginary + second.imaginary)
    def subtract(self, second):
        return Complex(self.real - second.real, self.imaginary - second.imaginary)
    def multiply(self, second):
        return Complex(self.real * second.real - self.imaginary * second.imaginary, self.imaginary * second.real + \
                       self.real * second.imaginary)
    def divide(self, second):
        x = float(second.real ** 2 + second.imaginary ** 2)
        return Complex(self.real * second.real + self.imaginary * second.imaginary)/(x) + (self.imaginary * second.real - self.real * second.imaginary)/(x)

x = Complex(5,-8)
y = Complex(-1,3)


print(Complex.multiply(x,y))
print(Complex.divide(x,y))
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2/PyCharmProjects/lab9/venv/lab9.3.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(Complex.divide(x,y))
  File "D:/PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2/PyCharmProjects/lab9/venv/lab9.3.py", line 16, in divide
    return Complex(self.real * second.real + self.imaginary * second.imaginary)/(x) + (self.imaginary * second.real - self.real * second.imaginary)/(x)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'imaginary'
```

So I've looked at other similar threads, and found something like initializing not only method but also class like Complex().divide(x,y), but then it say missing 2 arguments real and imaginary, any ideas with explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be something more like `print(x.multiply(y))`. But ideally, you'd probably rename the method to `__mul__` and just do `print(x * y)`.

Comment: Read that line. How many arguments do you think you're passing? How do you think the parentheses match up? Heck, do you even see any commas?

Comment: multiply function actually works completely fine

Comment: Perhaps, but I stand by my comment. And I mean do the same kind of thing for all the operations. But your immediate problem is in the `return` line of the `divide` method, as @user2357112 said. You don't pass both a real and imaginary value. If it were me, I'd probably make at least `imaginary` a keyword argument defaulted to 0.

Comment: Are you aware that Python has complex numbers built into the language?

Comment: I needed it done this way, that is the whole idea of this exercise

Answer (score 0):

You must first initialise your class with the parameters required for the `__init__` method and then, **using the instance** of the class, call whichever methods you wish.

```
x = Complex(5, -8)
y = Complex(-3, 3)
m = x.multiply(y)
d = x.divide(y)
print(m, d)
```

For initialised classes, the first parameter of their methods (`self`) is passed automatically; all you need is the rest. In your case the only parameter remaining to be passed is `second`.

**Update**

After taking a second look I realised that wasn't the source of your problem, although you should consider it as a guideline for good practice.

To solve your error, simply pass another parameter in the `Complex` declaration you initiate in your `divide` call. Your class currently requires two parameters and you are only passing one (pay close attention to the lack of a coma).

Comment: I still dont really understand. Where do i lack coma? 
    print(Complex.divide(x,y))  I am passing 2 arguments here: x and y, just like I wanted, what is the issue?

Comment: You are lacking a comma on the Complex definition before the return statement in your divide method.